# spark UDAF on range based window - How to get column value of original row from UDAF initialize/update for which aggregation is being computed

Tags: apache-spark, sliding-window

Spark UDAF on range based window - How to get column value of original row in UDAF initialize/update call for which aggregation is being computed. Window frame size in spark is fixed length. But in my case I want to dynamically/logically adjust the window size by having fixed window size but skipping update call for certain rows which does not match a criteria based on a column value from original row.